# NavigationBar hides View while runtime but not in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I set up a tableView with the Interface Builder and put a red View above the TableView like this:

[image]

But while runtime the red View gets hide by the Navigationbar, so i have to set a constraint with Autolayout like this:

[image]

But that can not be correct...what i´m doing wrong?

More Information which my help:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because iOS7 allows views to be displayed beneath it. You need to use an offset to push the view down below the navigation bar like you are doing. You could also set the navigation bar to not allow items beneath it by unchecking 
`under top bars`

[image]

If you use xibs instead of storyboard add this into your view controller.

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIEdgeRectNone;`

Comment: Sometimes Apple drives me really crazy....anyway that works perfect, thank you very much !!